# Input CV from LinkedIn

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, linkedin

Given that my Linked Profile already has a list of jobs, dates etc.  I would like to be able to **start** my careers CV by importing from my Linked Profile.

Comment: Interestingly, careers has close to no way of knowing you'd be starting with *your* LinkedIn profile. So such a tool would actually import *anyone's* profile. Not an argument against, just an observation....

Comment: @Craig, so what, I can copy in any one’s CV by hand anyway.  That is way references should be taken up for lots of past jobs.

Comment: if LinkedIn supported OpenID (maybe they do?), then you *could* conceivably only import a CV from the account that matched OpenIDs

Comment: fwiw - linkedin doe snot support openid yet

Comment: A good example of data portability issue... see http://dataportability.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Import from Facebook, LinkedIn (and soon hResume) is now possible.

Comment: Jeff, what happens if I import from LI into an already populated CV? I'm afraid to click the link for fear that it would overwrite or otherwise contaminate my CV. Should this option be hidden from CVs that already exist?

Comment: @prestaul we'll have that going into drafts, soon!

Comment: you're awesome!

Comment: It also rocks. Great implementation.

Comment: I suppose this answer is not correct now, according [this info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/274317/281907), so should be updated

Answer (score 4):

I concur - maintaining yet another source to be as up-to-date as the other is (I think) going to be a pain.

I already maintain: LinkedIn, resume file (doc & pdf), plus whatever various companies require if/when I apply there (though why they ***all*** don't support importing from LinkedIn or a pdf/rtf/txt format resume, I do not know).

Answer (score 4):

I also concur.
BTW:  Public profiles on LinkedIn are published marked-up in [hResume](http://microformats.org/wiki/hresume).  So there are already tools out there to parse this data.

Answer (score 0):

I got to this question exactly because I wanted to link my linkedin profile to CV.

LinkedIn is great for networking - which is by far the most effective way to land a job (you come recommended, you have their attention!). SO is great for showcasing your knowledge.

I don't want to maintain 4 different resumes (Linkedin, my favorite; Monster, losing relevance every day, but still a source of leads; resume file, because I still get - I have no freaking idea - requests for paper resumes if I just point people to an online source; and SO CV).

It would be ideal if CV would require a summary from the user and link to my LinkedIn profile and my SO track record.

Comment: There's a plus side to LI and CV being distinct.  CV is aimed at programming, and a lot of my LI resume would just be clutter for that purpose (I've done other things with my life than just programming, and could easily move back into them so I keep them on LI).

Answer (score -1):

If you are interested in exporting you cv resume data from linkedin I have written a web service to do so take a look at

http://www.onebiglink.com/cvexport

Comment: Not working. Is it alive?

Comment: Looks to be dead.