# Re-Sync LinkedIn Profile

Tags: support, jobs, linkedin

Is there a way to re-sync my linkedin.com profile instead of doing just a 'one time import'?

It would be great if I could update my LinkedIn (primary) then hit a button to update my Stack Exchange profile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no method of re-syncing a LinkedIn profile to your CV on Stack Overflow. We actually got rid of the "import from LinkedIn" feature entirely a couple months ago because LinkedIn changed the terms of service for their API, and we were no longer allowed to offer that integration.

Unless LinkedIn changes their terms of service again to be more like the old version, we won't be able to offer any import functionality, including an option to update / re-sync.

Comment: I'm really at a loss here. You migrated [this other question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316429/improve-location-of-export-tool-for-career-cv) over to MSO an hour ago, while posting reply on  this one here on MSE 15 minutes later. Any rules or way to know what will/should be migrated? People are downvoting (not me) and voting to close (I used to but stopped couple of days ago) and it is just creating lots of confusion and antagonism. Similar requests for support were vaguely dodged.

Comment: Similar requests for support were [vaguely dodged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/274213/152859). (Read the answer carefully. There is no real or solid advice there what to do.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I've been migrating questions to MSO when I come across one where non-mods have *already closed* the question as off-topic. Eventually, we want all Jobs related questions on MSO, but in reality, both places with both tags (jobs and careers) are monitored and the volume is low enough that we can manage fine for now. The community team is in charge of updating guidance and deciding on a cutoff date; I'll check with them to see what their plans are in that regard. I agree with you; it's confusing and kinda sucks.